# Spring batch: Executing multiple instance of a job in parallel with stateful beans

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

Here is my use case:

I have a code library (stateful) and I want to execute my spring batch job in parallel to
process data more than 1 record at the same time. But since my library is non thread safe, it would be impossible to use multi threading for running the batch without adding a custom setup.

Also, the code library is called during the ItemProcess of the job.

Here what I have tried so far:

1. I added a `@Scope("step")` in every java file that is stateful. This works fine in parellel except that performance greatly degrades. Even if there's only 1 thread, having `@Scope("step")` in the stateful beans degrade performance.

   For example: 
     100 data in 1 thread with no `@Scope("step")` processes data in 2 minutes.
     100 data in 1 thread with `@Scope("step)` process data in 4 minutes.

   (I don't know if there are overheads added when `@Scope("step")` is used)
2. For every data I received/read, I create a new `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and uses a JobLauncher with `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but somehow I get `NullPointerException` when running. It seems that some methods are already called even if the init() method was still not called. init() method is called by a service class to initialize the data of the stateful jobs. I also verified that I was indeed creating new instances of the code library per thread (verified by checking the hashCode of object) but I couldn't explain why it was not calling it's method sequentially. Note that JobLauncher is declared in every applicationContext.
3. I remove the JobLauncher and placed it in a parent applicationContext to have a singleton of JobLauncher. I'm still creating the applicationContext per data but I am adding the parent applicationContext during creation. JobLauncher is still `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but I set the `tasklet-executor` of the tasklet of my job to `SyncTaskExecutor`. When I ran it, it freezes at some point (console in my eclipse has stop updating)

As much as possible, I would not want to refactor the library code to change it to thread safe since this library was made by another team.

What should be the best approach when dealing with stateful beans in an multi threading environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Any particular reason why you create a new spring context with each data read? 2) I can't fully imagine what "using the library" means, but unless it consists of singletons, you might create your own classes to be called by spring batch, and synchronize the access to the instances of the library objects while processing the items

Comment: 1 - This is so that I could have new fresh beans; 2 - Yes they were coded as singletons with states. I know that is bad design

Comment: For the usage of the library, there is 1 entry point in the library. This entry point is a service. This service is called in the ItemProcessor and data is passed thru parameter

Comment: assuming the data can be partitioned, did you think about packaging x batch components, deploying them all and get "parallelism" via "almost parallel" starting the batches with different partition boundaries?

Comment: @MichaelPralow Do you mean a 1 threaded batch application x n in a server? If yes, I did consider that. Data partitioning wouldn't also be a problem. But I was also thinking I don't want to manage the batch instances outside the system. As much as possible, I'd like to have it under 1 jar file. But if I really have no choice, I will have to resort to that strategy. I'm just looking for other options that are cleaner, more efficient and effective.

Comment: Can you share the configurations you've tried?  StepScope shouldn't have any performance degradation.  The only overhead it adds is the creation of the objects.  So in your case, I'd expect the degradation to be coming from the creation of the extra instances.